# Parse IP addresses from txt

Tags: python, regex, parsing, ip

I'm trying to download a **txt** file which you can find [here](http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/free-proxy-list.txt). Downloading the file is not a problem:

```
    testfile = urllib.URLopener()
    testfile.retrieve(_proxy_list_download_, "proxies.txt")
```

But the problem is that when it is downloaded it acts weird. When I open it in any **txt** editor, I can see the content and **IP** addresses but when I try to print the content  into the console it prints this:

```
212.3.183.210:8080; 0; 0; anonymous proxy; Italy; ; a;  in); an Jose); ree download proxy IP
```

And when I try to get **IP** addresses from there, there is no address in the output.

```
with open('proxies.txt') as f:
            content = f.read()
            ip = re.findall( r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", content )
```

I've tried already another **regex**:

```
r'([0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+){3}'
```

This **regex** returned only **3-digit** numbers.

Do you have any idea how to parse those IPs?

EDIT: Here is the copy+pasted text from text editor but in the editor everything is in one line:

```
 # http://proxy-ip-list.com/ provides you this fresh txt proxy list to free download proxy IP
# Date: Sat, 27 Jun 2015 12:53:02 +0000

39.166.95.9:8123; 0; 0; high-anonymous; China; 
178.189.92.118:3129; 16.83; 405; high-anonymous; Austria; 
198.2.202.33:8090; 8.05; 884; anonymous; United States (CA, San Jose); 
171.96.152.89:8080; 0; 0; anonymous; Thailand; 
153.149.104.76:80; 0; 0; anonymous; Japan (Tokyo); 
106.187.52.191:80; 0; 0; anonymous proxy; Japan; 
194.187.214.204:80; 0.91; 6374; anonymous proxy; Finland; 
59.78.160.247:8080; 0; 0; anonymous; China (Shanghai); 
61.156.3.166:80; 1.12; 1449; anonymous proxy; China (Jinan); 
221.238.140.164:8080; 1.39; 257; anonymous; China (Tianjin); 
117.178.157.107:8123; 8.44; 847; high-anonymous; China; 
39.166.205.95:8123; 0; 0; high-anonymous; China; 
117.163.216.8:8123; 4.21; 1577; high-anonymous; China; 
189.31.143.250:3128; 0; 0; high-anonymous; Brazil; 
183.89.84.82:8080; 0; 0; anonymous proxy; Thailand; 
183.88.41.42:8080; 0; 0; anonymous; Thailand; 
212.3.183.210:8080; 0; 0; anonymous proxy; Italy;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove anchors, since a line won't contain only a single ip-address.

```
ip = re.findall( r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", content )
```

second regex

```
r'([0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+){3}'
```

must return three digit number because only the first three digits are captured, `re.findall` method would return captures first if there any.  If there are no captures, then only it would return the matches. By turning the capturing group into non-capturing group will give you the desired output.

```
r'\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}\b'
```